# ArcPy Python Script To Update Shapefile Records From CSVs

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, csv, update

I am fairly new to python scripting. Most of the basics I have down however still learning.

I am trying to create a python script to update a shapefile with information from two separate CSV files. There is a common attribute that will link the CSV records to the Shapefile. I want to update the records of the shapefile with information from provided in the CSV files.

I found a script from a website that appears to do what I am looking for (link below), however when I run the script it it **errors on line 11: for row2 in cursor2 and states: "Runtime Error; Invalid SQL Statement"**. I have tried several different attempts to negate the issue to no avail. If anyone could point out what is wrong with the script or if you have a more efficient way to create a script to accomplish my goal I am all ears.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/Data"

print 'Processing...'

fc = "parcels.shp"

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["APN"])
for row in cursor:
  SQL_stat= "APN = "+ str(row[0])
  fc2 = "Numerical_CSV.csv" 

cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["ASSESSMENT"], SQL_stat)
for row2 in cursor2:
  UpdatedValue = row2[0]
  cursor3 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc2, ["TAXYEAR"],SQL_stat)
    for row3 in cursor3:
        row3[0] = UpdatedValue
        cursor3.updateRow(row3)
del row
del cursor
del row2
del cursor2
del row3
del cursor3

print "Done"
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to use the [edit] button beneath your question to improve it by replacing the picture of your code with a code snippet as text so that it can be copy/pasted for testing and searched, please?

Comment: this isn't what you're asking about, but would I recommend using `with` statements in your cursors so that you don't have to `del` them.

Comment: also, I think the indentation at the start of the inner `for` loop is off.

Comment: It's a pretty inefficient construct to initiate a cursor within each row of a cursor within each row of a cursor. I would recommend reading values into dictionaries before entering the update cursor.

Comment: I can't find any evidence that arcpy cursors work on csv files. You should read the values from the csv using python's built-in csv module.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting a field in a shapefile you need to surround the field name (e.g. FID) with quotes:

```
SQL_stat = '"FID" = {}'.format(row[0])
```

Comment: In fact if you use AddFieldDelimiters, it will be less error-prone, such as SQL_stat= "{0} = {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,"APN"),str(row[0])